# how to merge the objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Explanation: merge the objects, `t_f`and `t_t` become as key and `v` become value. in `t_f_t` object. after that `t_f_t` document will merge into `data`. check the expected output.

```
{
  "data": {
    "2011-08-31T05:33:02Z": 1,
    "2011-09-01T12:58:33Z": 1,
 
  },
  "t_f_t": {
    "t_f": "2010-07-25T22:07:00Z",
    "t_t": "2020-10-06T21:07:00Z",
    "v": 0
  }
}
```

Output document

```
{
  "data": {
    "2010-07-25T22:07:00Z": 0,
    "2011-08-31T05:33:02Z": 1,
    "2011-09-01T12:58:33Z": 1,
    "2020-10-06T21:07:00Z": 0,
    
  },
```

Comment: Is this a homework? What did you try so far? Are the keys `t_f` and `t_t` fix?

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes keys `t_f` and `t_t` are fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         t: [
            { k: "$t_f_t.t_f", v: "$t_f_t.v" },
            { k: "$t_f_t.t_t", v: "$t_f_t.v" }
         ]
      }
   },
   { $set: { t: { $arrayToObject: "$t" } } },
   { $project: { data: { $mergeObjects: ["$data", "$t"] } } },
])
```

If you need a more dynamic one, then use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { t: { $objectToArray: "$t_f_t" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         t: {
            $map: {
               input: "$t",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $ne: ["$$this.k", "v"] },
                     then: { k: "$$this.v", v: "$t_f_t.v" },
                     else: null
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { t: { $filter: { input: "$t", cond: "$$this" } } } },
   { $set: { t: { $arrayToObject: "$t" } } },
   { $project: { data: { $mergeObjects: ["$data", "$t"] } } },
])
```

Comment: Thanks its worked, It solves the issue, but I don't understand why sorting is not working, I try to do a sort on time. but its not sorted.

Comment: Fields in an object do not have any order!

Comment: I understand this point, the next stepI already give is the field name. but still its not sorted.

Comment: Again, you cannot sort the fields in object. You would have to transpose to an array.